# Error while calling Navigation Components while using ViewPager 2

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, retrofit, android-architecture-navigation

I have a hard time with trying to learn `Navigation Components`.
In my app, I have 6 fragments.

- Four of them are swipeable by using `ViewPager 2`
- Fifth fragment is not implemented in `ViewPager`, so user can't go there by swipping
- Sixth fragment is just a host for `ViewPager`, since the other fragments are used by `Navigation Components`

I can swipe fragments for now, but whenever I try to use `Navigation Components`, I getting error about `action/destionation`. It's simply about calling for example `ActionFrag1ToFrag5` from my `Host Fragment`

It seems like I can browse through fragments, but I can't cast any `Navigation Component` functions, because the fragment stays the same, it doesn't change label after swipe to another one.

Is there a way to get proper `NavController` from specific fragment, or it's just my poor implementation?

Comment: How are you getting the NavController?

Comment: @TheLibrarian tried to do it in two ways. 1: findNavController().navigate(R.id.ACTION_ID)  2: val provideFragmentName = FragDirections.fragNavigate()
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)
.navigate(R.id.ACTION_ID)

Comment: What is the starting direction?

Comment: @TheLibrarian it's Frag1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Frag1`, `Frag2`, `Frag3`, and `Frag4` are those in the `ViewPager` and you want to go to `Frag5`.

The direction needs to be from the `Frag6` that is hosting the `ViewPager` to the `Frag5`.

Comment: I got it. Just hardcoded navigation for now, but it seems to be working. I just need to figure out the best way to provide data to this fragment. Thank you, once again.